# $f$ is monotone increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ . Prove that the set $\{x: \forall \epsilon > 0, f(x+\epsilon)> f(x-\epsilon) \}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$f$ is monotone increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ . Prove that the set $\{x: \forall \epsilon > 0, f(x+\epsilon)> f(x-\epsilon) \}$ is closed.

I want to change the set into $$\cap_{\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}^+} \{x:f(x+\epsilon)\gt f(x-\epsilon)\}$$
and see if there is a correlation between it and the close set. But it's not a intersection of countable interval.

Comment: Well, if $f$ is increasing, then $f(x+\epsilon)>f(x-\epsilon)$ holds for any $x$ and any $\epsilon>0$

Comment: If it is *strictly* increasing.

Comment: Maybe a translation problem: The correct English term is "monotonic"..... "Monotonous" has a very different (non-mathematical) meaning.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: show instead that the set $$\left\{x\in\mathbb R\,\big{|}\,\exists\,\varepsilon>0:f(x+\varepsilon)\leq f(x-\varepsilon)\right\}$$ is open.

Comment: for $x_0$ in the set. I need to find a open interval around it  such that the open interval is included in the set. But how to use the term monotonous increasing to make it .

Comment: Monotonicity implies that, in fact, $f(x+\varepsilon)=f(x-\varepsilon)$, therefore $f$ is constant in $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \forall \epsilon > 0, f(x+\epsilon)> f(x-\epsilon) \}$ which converges to $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

We wish to show that $x_0 \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \forall \epsilon > 0, f(x+\epsilon)> f(x-\epsilon) \}$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Pick $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_0 - x_n| < \frac\varepsilon2$. This is equivalent to $x_0 \in \left\langle x_n - \frac\varepsilon2, x_n + \frac\varepsilon2\right\rangle$.

We then have $x_0 + \varepsilon > x_n + \frac\varepsilon2$ and $x_n - \frac\varepsilon2 > x_0 - \varepsilon$. Therefore

$$f(x_0+\varepsilon) \ge f\left(x_n + \frac\varepsilon2\right) > f\left(x_n - \frac\varepsilon2\right) \ge f(x_0-\varepsilon)$$

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude $x_0 \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \forall \epsilon > 0, f(x+\epsilon)> f(x-\epsilon)\}$.

Therefore $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \forall \epsilon > 0, f(x+\epsilon)> f(x-\epsilon) \}$ is closed.

Comment: I had a similar answer, but yours is better. So I deleted mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take the complement, and show it contains an interval around each of its points.

> $x$ being in the complement means there is $\varepsilon>0$ with $f(x+\varepsilon)=f(x-\varepsilon)$. Now $f$ must be constant on $[x-\varepsilon, \, x+\varepsilon]$, and thus every point of $(x-\varepsilon, \, x+\varepsilon)$ is in the complement.

Comment: This is just stating one definition of closed sets and does not provide an answer specific to the Question in any respect.  Please expand your Answer to make it relate to the problem or delete and repost it as a Comment.